# Check mark gets cut off for short answers

Tags: bug, design, android-app, accepted-answer

The check mark on accepted answers gets cut off for short answers in the Android app.

> [image]

The answer in question is https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/2355/481.

(It was accepted while I was viewing the question; however, the bug persisted after refreshing the question)

Comment: [Looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxAjR.jpg) for me. LG G5, Android 7.

Comment: @alexolut Huh. It's showing up fine now for me as well. Guess it's an edge case, just for when the answer is accepted while you're looking at the question.